# XMPP bosh server setup

Tags: ejabberd

I have installed ejabberd on a centos 6.5 and working fine with psi and other XMPP clients.
But I could not connect it using strophe api. my goal is using it with phonegap for mobile phones.

I am following this toturial : http://blog.wolfspelz.de/2010/09/website-chat-made-easy-with-xmpp-and.html

and I did these changes under httpd.conf:

```
<Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass xmpp-httpbind/ http://my.server.ip:5280/http-bind/ 
ProxyPassReverse xmpp-httpbind/ http://my.server.ip:5280/http-bind/
```

after restarting httpd, 
http://my.server.ip/xmpp-httpbind say "service temporarily unavailable",
but http://my.server.ip:5280/http-bind say "ejabberd mod_http_bind" and seems to be ok.

I also tried to do it using .htaccess, but no success.

Any help would be appreciated.